# Enscript: where is the AFM folder located at on OSX?

Tags: printing, terminal, fonts, enscript

I installed enscript thru `brew install enscript`

Normally AFM folder located at `/usr/share/enscript/afm` but no such directory.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/Cellar/enscript/$VERSION/share/enscript/afm/`

replace `$VERSION` with your version folder, in my case, it's `1.6.6_1`

Answer (score 0):

---

#### (if installed via `Macports`)

---

open `/opt/local/etc/enscript.cfg` which is what tells enscript where things are.

In my case, after an install of enscript via `macports` it had this to say:

```
# Lookup path for the AFM files.
AFMPath: /opt/local/share/enscript/afm:/usr/local/lib/ps:/usr/lib/ps
```

Those directories don't all *have to* exist, but the one for me was `/opt/local/share/enscript/afm`.

If you are looking for *font names* (and remember the command line format is `-f <name><size>` as in `-f Courier5`, then look to

`/opt/local/share/enscript/afm/font.map`

```
AvantGarde-Demi                 agd
AvantGarde-DemiOblique          agdo
AvantGarde-Book                 agw
AvantGarde-BookOblique          agwo
Bookman-Demi                    bkd
Bookman-DemiItalic              bkdi
Bookman-Light                   bkl
Bookman-LightItalic             bkli
Courier-Bold                    cob
Courier-BoldOblique             cobo
Courier                         com
Courier-Oblique                 coo
Helvetica                       hv
Helvetica-Bold                  hvb
Helvetica-BoldOblique           hvbo
Helvetica-Condensed             hvc
Helvetica-Condensed-Bold        hvcb
Helvetica-Condensed-BoldObl     hvcbo
Helvetica-Condensed-Oblique     hvcdo
Helvetica-Narrow                hvn
Helvetica-Narrow-Bold           hvnb
Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique    hvnbo
Helvetica-Narrow-Oblique        hvno
Helvetica-Oblique               hvo
Matrix                          matrix
NewCenturySchlbk-Bold           ncb
NewCenturySchlbk-BoldItalic     ncbi
NewCenturySchlbk-Italic         nci
NewCenturySchlbk-Roman          ncr
Palatino-Bold                   pob
Palatino-BoldItalic             pobi
Palatino-Italic                 poi
Palatino-Roman                  por
Symbol                          sy
Times-Bold                      tib
Times-BoldItalic                tibi
Times-Italic                    tii
Times-Roman                     tir
ZapfChancery-MediumItalic       zcmi
ZapfDingbats                    zd
```